# Running Powershell scripts on Web App machine

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-deployment

I have an Azure web app.  This web app has a QA deployment slot for pre-production testing.  When I check in my code from VS, I have it setup to build and deploy to the QA deployment slot.  This works great.  However, a few configurations need to be updated in the QA web app so the application points to the correct service endpoints (i.e. not dev).  To do this, my initial approach was to add a PS task to the Release that unzips my deployment zip, updates the configuration files, rezips them and then allows the Release flow to deploy the updated zip.  This works locally, but running into filename length issues on the server when unzipping, which I can't change.

Now I'm trying to just include my update PS scripts in my deployment package, and then run the scripts AFTER the deployment has occurred.  So, I'm looking at this Powershell on Target Machines task to run a PS on the QA slot server to update configurations.  However, it's asking for Machines, which would be the server name of the slot server.  I don't have that.  I also don't know where to get it.  I also don't have the path to the PS scripts once I have the server name.  I dumped out the server variables and none of them help me, unless there is a cmdlet to look up environments that I'm not aware of.

```
System.DefaultWorkingDirectory: 'C:\a\2ed23b64d'
System.TeamFoundationServerUri: 'https://REDACTED.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/'
System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri: 'https://REDACTEDvisualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/'
System.TeamProject: 'REDACTED'
System.TeamProjectId: 'REDACTED'
Release.DefinitionName: 'REDACTED'
Release.EnvironmentUri: 'vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/46'
Release.EnvironmentName: 'QA'
Release.ReleaseDescription: 'Triggered by REDACTED Build Definition 20160425.4.'
Release.ReleaseId: '31'
Release.ReleaseName: 'Release-31'
Release.ReleaseUri: 'vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/31'
Release.RequestedFor: 'Matthew Mulhearn'
Release.RequestedForId: ''
Agent.HomeDirectory: 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1'
Agent.JobName: 'Release' 
Agent.MachineName: 'TASKAGENT5-0020' 
Agent.Name: 'Hosted Agent'
Agent.RootDirectory: 'C:\a'
Agent.WorkingDirectory: 'C:\a\SourceRootMapping\REDACTED' 
Agent.ReleaseDirectory: 'C:\a\2ed23b64d'
```

Anyone have any idea, or a better approach, to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Comment: Did you try start with VS TS build definition and release management?

Comment: The VSTS build and release management is what I'm using, yes.

Comment: webapp is basically IIS instances running on Azure platform, it doesn't feature as a server or VM. You can run powershell script as a webjob, but this should not be a preferred option for altering configuration files. I believe Alex's suggestion is having VS TS handle the config before you deploy. If you have another deployment tool they may be able to unpack cspkg and alter config then repack before deploy. Last, I heard you can assign configs to designated deployment slot in azure, but I never had a chance to try this yet.